# Active projects Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

How can I get a list of active project in Teamcity?
We want to migrate everything to Bamboo, and I would like to do an sort of inventory of which projects are actively are being used to build code.By the way, I'm new to Teamcity, have never worked with it before.

Comment: from the database or from the backup?

Comment: or some script or api. from database is ok